# MITM with Netty 5.0: Browser unable to receive full http response

Tags: java, proxy, netty

I am building a MITM proxy with Netty 5.0. This is basically an educational project, just for myself to learn how to build a MITM proxy and how to use Netty. In the meantime, I am using WebDriver to programmatically make a browser to use the MITM proxy for testing purposes.

Conceptually, it is straightforward to me, at least for HTTP (HTTPS needs some extra handling, but shouldn't be too difficult). Here is what I have in my mind for the structure of the MITM proxy.

First, the proxy needs two pipelines. One connects the browser and the proxy (let's call it server pipeline). The other one connects the proxy to the Internet (let's call it client pipeline). So, the overall structure will be something like this:
**Browser <---server pipeline---> MITM Proxy <---client pipeline--->Internet**

Second, the server pipeline can be constructed like below:

```
public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
    p.addLast(SERVER_LOGGING_HANDLER, new LoggingHandler(SERVER_LOGGING_HANDLER, LogLevel.DEBUG))
            .addLast(HTTP_SERVER_CODEC, new HttpServerCodec())
            .addLast(HTTP_CONTENT_AGGREGATOR, new HttpObjectAggregator(MAX_HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH))
            .addLast(SERVER_HANDLER, new ServerHandler(ch));
}
```

And the client pipeline can be constructed like below:

```
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
    p.addLast(CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER, new LoggingHandler(CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER, LogLevel.DEBUG))
            .addLast(HTTP_CLIENT_CODEC, new HttpClientCodec())
            .addLast(HTTP_CONTENT_AGGREGATOR, new HttpObjectAggregator(MAX_HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH))
            .addLast(CLIENT_HANDLER, new ClientHandler(ServerHandler.this, ch));
}
```

In the above code, the `ServerHandler` and `ClientHandler` are my custom classes. What `ClientHandler` does is call `ServerHandler` to write its received content to browser. Below are relevant code from the two classes:

```
// ClientHandler
private ServerHandler serverHandler;
@Override
protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpObject msg) throws Exception {
    log.info("client pipeline handlers: " + ctx.pipeline().names());
    if (msg instanceof FullHttpResponse) {
        FullHttpResponse response = (FullHttpResponse) msg;
        log.info("Received HTTP response:\n{}", response);
        serverHandler.writeResponse(msg);
    } else {
        ... // exception case
    }
}

// ServerHandler
public void writeResponse(HttpObject httpObject) {
    log.info("Is FullHttpResponse? {}", httpObject instanceof FullHttpResponse);
    ChannelHandlerContext context = channel.pipeline().context(this);
    context.writeAndFlush(httpObject);
    log.debug("sent response back to client");
}
```

I used a netty javadoc page in a test. Below are some relevant lines:

```
EventFiringWebDriver driver = null;
try {
    driver = getChromeDriver(proxyAddr); // get a ChromeDriver with the given proxyAddr as proxy
    driver.get("http://netty.io/5.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html");
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
...
```

From the proxy log, I can see that it is able to handle the proxying as expected. However, in the last step, namely, sending the javadoc page content to the browser, something seems broken. Specifically, the FullHttpResponse has content length over 10KB, but only less than 1KB data was sent to the browser (Chrome). As the browser didn't receive the entire content, it just kept waiting with "data," in the address bar.

Below are logs that may help to understand the problem (I deleted most formatted output from LoggingHandler's, only kept some):

```
2014-12-04 22:58:19.428 [Test worker] DEBUG MultithreadEventLoopGroup:debug(): -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 16
2014-12-04 22:58:19.440 [Test worker] DEBUG NioEventLoop:debug(): -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
2014-12-04 22:58:19.440 [Test worker] DEBUG NioEventLoop:debug(): -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
2014-12-04 22:58:19.448 [Test worker] INFO  ProxyServer:start(): Starting proxy server.
2014-12-04 22:58:19.453 [Test worker] INFO  ProxyServer:initPorts(): Binding port 10001
2014-12-04 22:58:19.460 [Test worker] DEBUG DefaultChannelId:debug(): -Dio.netty.machineId: b8:e8:56:45:4f:e8:00:00 (auto-detected)
2014-12-04 22:58:19.461 [Test worker] DEBUG DefaultChannelId:debug(): -Dio.netty.processId: 47735 (auto-detected)
2014-12-04 22:58:19.463 [Test worker] DEBUG ThreadLocalRandom:debug(): -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0x0ee5184323c884e4
2014-12-04 22:58:19.469 [Test worker] DEBUG ChannelOutboundBuffer:debug(): -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
2014-12-04 22:58:19.489 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent:debug(): UID: 83297
2014-12-04 22:58:19.490 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent:debug(): Java version: 7
2014-12-04 22:58:19.490 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent:debug(): -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
2014-12-04 22:58:19.491 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent0:debug(): java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner: available
2014-12-04 22:58:19.492 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent0:debug(): java.nio.Buffer.address: available
2014-12-04 22:58:19.492 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent0:debug(): sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
2014-12-04 22:58:19.493 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent0:debug(): sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
2014-12-04 22:58:19.494 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent0:debug(): java.nio.Bits.unaligned: true
2014-12-04 22:58:19.494 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent:debug(): sun.misc.Unsafe: available
2014-12-04 22:58:19.495 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent:debug(): -Dio.netty.noJavassist: false
2014-12-04 22:58:19.564 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent:debug(): Javassist: available
2014-12-04 22:58:19.564 [Test worker] DEBUG PlatformDependent:debug(): -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
2014-12-04 22:58:19.568 [Test worker] DEBUG NetUtil:debug(): Loopback interface: lo0
2014-12-04 22:58:19.568 [Test worker] DEBUG NetUtil:debug(): Loopback address: /fe80:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1 (primary)
2014-12-04 22:58:19.569 [Test worker] DEBUG NetUtil:debug(): Loopback address: /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
2014-12-04 22:58:19.569 [Test worker] DEBUG NetUtil:debug(): Loopback address: /127.0.0.1
2014-12-04 22:58:19.576 [Test worker] INFO  ProxyServer:initPorts(): is 10001 bound? true
2014-12-04 22:58:19.576 [Test worker] INFO  ProxyServer:initPorts(): Binding port 10002
2014-12-04 22:58:19.578 [Test worker] INFO  ProxyServer:initPorts(): is 10002 bound? true

Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248307) on port 44495
2014-12-04 22:58:22.581 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG ResourceLeakDetector:debug(): -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel: simple
2014-12-04 22:58:22.599 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG JavassistTypeParameterMatcherGenerator:debug(): Generated: io.netty.util.internal.__matchers__.io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectMatcher
2014-12-04 22:58:22.604 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG SERVER_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xad3d76c2, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57916 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10001] REGISTERED
2014-12-04 22:58:22.605 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG SERVER_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xad3d76c2, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57916 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10001] ACTIVE
2014-12-04 22:58:22.606 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG SERVER_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xad3d76c2, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57916 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10001] RECEIVED: 413B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.615 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  ServerHandler:channelRead(): server pipeline handlers: [SERVER_LOGGING_HANDLER, HttpRequestDecoder#0, HttpResponseEncoder#0, HTTP_CONTENT_AGGREGATOR, SERVER_HANDLER, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailHandler#0]
2014-12-04 22:58:22.616 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO  ServerHandler:handleInternetTraffic(): Received full request:
DefaultFullHttpRequest, decodeResult: success)
GET http://netty.io/5.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html HTTP/1.1
Host: netty.io
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Length: 0
2014-12-04 22:58:22.616 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG ServerHandler:sendToInternet(): uri: http://netty.io/5.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html
2014-12-04 22:58:22.680 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  ClientHandler:<init>(): Constructing new ClientHandler...
2014-12-04 22:58:22.682 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032] REGISTERED
2014-12-04 22:58:22.682 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032] CONNECT: netty.io/104.28.8.44:80
2014-12-04 22:58:22.699 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] ACTIVE
2014-12-04 22:58:22.699 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  ClientHandler:write(): Write outbound message.
2014-12-04 22:58:22.700 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG SERVER_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xad3d76c2, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57916 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10001] FLUSH
2014-12-04 22:58:22.702 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] WRITE: 432B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.702 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] FLUSH
2014-12-04 22:58:22.879 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d |HTTP/1.1 200 OK.|
|00000010| 0a 44 61 74 65 3a 20 46 72 69 2c 20 30 35 20 44 |.Date: Fri, 05 D|
|00000020| 65 63 20 32 30 31 34 20 30 36 3a 35 38 3a 32 32 |ec 2014 06:58:22|
|00000030| 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 | GMT..Content-Ty|
|00000040| 70 65 3a 20 74 65 78 74 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3b 20 63 |pe: text/html; c|
|00000050| 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 75 74 66 2d 38 0d 0a 54 72 |harset=utf-8..Tr|
|00000060| 61 6e 73 66 65 72 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a |ansfer-Encoding:|
|00000070| 20 63 68 75 6e 6b 65 64 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 | chunked..Connec|
|00000080| 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20 6b 65 65 70 2d 61 6c 69 76 65 |tion: keep-alive|
|00000090| 0d 0a 53 65 74 2d 43 6f 6f 6b 69 65 3a 20 5f 5f |..Set-Cookie: __|
|000000a0| 63 66 64 75 69 64 3d 64 65 65 37 66 34 65 33 30 |cfduid=dee7f4e30|
|000000b0| 64 33 30 65 31 63 64 37 33 33 30 63 63 33 35 65 |d30e1cd7330cc35e|
|000000c0| 38 65 30 66 38 63 37 36 31 34 31 37 37 36 32 37 |8e0f8c7614177627|
|000000d0| 30 32 3b 20 65 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d 53 61 74 2c |02; expires=Sat,|
|000000e0| 20 30 35 2d 44 65 63 2d 31 35 20 30 36 3a 35 38 | 05-Dec-15 06:58|
|000000f0| 3a 32 32 20 47 4d 54 3b 20 70 61 74 68 3d 2f 3b |:22 GMT; path=/;|
|00000100| 20 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e 3d 2e 6e 65 74 74 79 2e 69 | domain=.netty.i|
|00000110| 6f 3b 20 48 74 74 70 4f 6e 6c 79 0d 0a 4c 61 73 |o; HttpOnly..Las|
|00000120| 74 2d 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 3a 20 54 68 75 2c |t-Modified: Thu,|
|00000130| 20 30 34 20 44 65 63 20 32 30 31 34 20 31 32 3a | 04 Dec 2014 12:|
|00000140| 31 32 3a 33 36 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 45 78 70 69 72 |12:36 GMT..Expir|
|00000150| 65 73 3a 20 46 72 69 2c 20 30 35 20 44 65 63 20 |es: Fri, 05 Dec |
|00000160| 32 30 31 34 20 30 37 3a 30 38 3a 32 32 20 47 4d |2014 07:08:22 GM|
|00000170| 54 0d 0a 43 61 63 68 65 2d 43 6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c |T..Cache-Control|
|00000180| 3a 20 6d 61 78 2d 61 67 65 3d 36 30 30 0d 0a 56 |: max-age=600..V|
|00000190| 61 72 79 3a 20 41 63 63 65 70 74 2d 45 6e 63 6f |ary: Accept-Enco|
|000001a0| 64 69 6e 67 0d 0a 53 65 72 76 65 72 3a 20 63 6c |ding..Server: cl|
|000001b0| 6f 75 64 66 6c 61 72 65 2d 6e 67 69 6e 78 0d 0a |oudflare-nginx..|
|000001c0| 43 46 2d 52 41 59 3a 20 31 39 33 65 35 61 64 38 |CF-RAY: 193e5ad8|
|000001d0| 63 33 39 33 30 36 36 33 2d 53 4a 43 0d 0a 43 6f |c3930663-SJC..Co|
|000001e0| 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20 |ntent-Encoding: |
<more>
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
2014-12-04 22:58:22.887 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.891 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.894 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.895 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.896 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.897 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.900 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.902 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.904 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.905 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.907 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 1024B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.908 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 569B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.933 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xeafd0032, /192.168.1.134:57917 => netty.io/104.28.8.44:80] RECEIVED: 945B
2014-12-04 22:58:22.934 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  ClientHandler:messageReceived(): client pipeline handlers: [CLIENT_LOGGING_HANDLER, HttpClientCodec$Decoder#0, HttpClientCodec$Encoder#0, HTTP_CONTENT_AGGREGATOR, CLIENT_HANDLER, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailHandler#0]
2014-12-04 22:58:22.935 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  ClientHandler:messageReceived(): Received HTTP response:
DefaultFullHttpResponse(decodeResult: success)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 06:58:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dee7f4e30d30e1cd7330cc35e8e0f8c761417762702; expires=Sat, 05-Dec-15 06:58:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.netty.io; HttpOnly
Last-Modified: Thu, 04 Dec 2014 12:12:36 GMT
Expires: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 07:08:22 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 193e5ad8c3930663-SJC
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 13061
2014-12-04 22:58:22.935 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  ServerHandler:writeResponse(): Is FullHttpResponse? true
2014-12-04 22:58:22.936 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG ServerHandler:writeResponse(): httpObject size? DefaultFullHttpResponse(decodeResult: success)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 06:58:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dee7f4e30d30e1cd7330cc35e8e0f8c761417762702; expires=Sat, 05-Dec-15 06:58:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.netty.io; HttpOnly
Last-Modified: Thu, 04 Dec 2014 12:12:36 GMT
Expires: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 07:08:22 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 193e5ad8c3930663-SJC
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 13061
2014-12-04 22:58:22.936 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] DEBUG ServerHandler:writeResponse(): sent response back to client
2014-12-04 22:58:22.937 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG SERVER_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xad3d76c2, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57916 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10001] WRITE: 499B
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d |HTTP/1.1 200 OK.|
|00000010| 0a 44 61 74 65 3a 20 46 72 69 2c 20 30 35 20 44 |.Date: Fri, 05 D|
|00000020| 65 63 20 32 30 31 34 20 30 36 3a 35 38 3a 32 32 |ec 2014 06:58:22|
|00000030| 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 | GMT..Content-Ty|
|00000040| 70 65 3a 20 74 65 78 74 2f 68 74 6d 6c 3b 20 63 |pe: text/html; c|
|00000050| 68 61 72 73 65 74 3d 75 74 66 2d 38 0d 0a 43 6f |harset=utf-8..Co|
|00000060| 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20 6b 65 65 70 2d 61 |nnection: keep-a|
|00000070| 6c 69 76 65 0d 0a 53 65 74 2d 43 6f 6f 6b 69 65 |live..Set-Cookie|
|00000080| 3a 20 5f 5f 63 66 64 75 69 64 3d 64 65 65 37 66 |: __cfduid=dee7f|
|00000090| 34 65 33 30 64 33 30 65 31 63 64 37 33 33 30 63 |4e30d30e1cd7330c|
|000000a0| 63 33 35 65 38 65 30 66 38 63 37 36 31 34 31 37 |c35e8e0f8c761417|
|000000b0| 37 36 32 37 30 32 3b 20 65 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d |762702; expires=|
|000000c0| 53 61 74 2c 20 30 35 2d 44 65 63 2d 31 35 20 30 |Sat, 05-Dec-15 0|
|000000d0| 36 3a 35 38 3a 32 32 20 47 4d 54 3b 20 70 61 74 |6:58:22 GMT; pat|
|000000e0| 68 3d 2f 3b 20 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e 3d 2e 6e 65 74 |h=/; domain=.net|
|000000f0| 74 79 2e 69 6f 3b 20 48 74 74 70 4f 6e 6c 79 0d |ty.io; HttpOnly.|
|00000100| 0a 4c 61 73 74 2d 4d 6f 64 69 66 69 65 64 3a 20 |.Last-Modified: |
|00000110| 54 68 75 2c 20 30 34 20 44 65 63 20 32 30 31 34 |Thu, 04 Dec 2014|
|00000120| 20 31 32 3a 31 32 3a 33 36 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 45 | 12:12:36 GMT..E|
|00000130| 78 70 69 72 65 73 3a 20 46 72 69 2c 20 30 35 20 |xpires: Fri, 05 |
|00000140| 44 65 63 20 32 30 31 34 20 30 37 3a 30 38 3a 32 |Dec 2014 07:08:2|
|00000150| 32 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 43 61 63 68 65 2d 43 6f 6e |2 GMT..Cache-Con|
|00000160| 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 6d 61 78 2d 61 67 65 3d 36 30 |trol: max-age=60|
|00000170| 30 0d 0a 56 61 72 79 3a 20 41 63 63 65 70 74 2d |0..Vary: Accept-|
|00000180| 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 0d 0a 53 65 72 76 65 72 |Encoding..Server|
|00000190| 3a 20 63 6c 6f 75 64 66 6c 61 72 65 2d 6e 67 69 |: cloudflare-ngi|
|000001a0| 6e 78 0d 0a 43 46 2d 52 41 59 3a 20 31 39 33 65 |nx..CF-RAY: 193e|
|000001b0| 35 61 64 38 63 33 39 33 30 36 36 33 2d 53 4a 43 |5ad8c3930663-SJC|
|000001c0| 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 |..Content-Encodi|
|000001d0| 6e 67 3a 20 67 7a 69 70 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e |ng: gzip..Conten|
|000001e0| 74 2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 31 33 30 36 31 0d |t-Length: 13061.|
|000001f0| 0a 0d 0a                                        |...             |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
2014-12-04 22:58:22.937 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] DEBUG SERVER_LOGGING_HANDLER:debug(): [id: 0xad3d76c2, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57916 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:10001] FLUSH
```

The logs may be not so straightforward since I didn't paste all my code, but I hope you can find evidence that the proxy is able to pass browser's request and get response from the internet in the above logs. From the last portion of the logs, you can see the received Content-Length is 13061, but only 499B data is sent back to browser. BTW, nothing happens after that. I am completely confused by this result, as in the `ServerHandler.writeRespone(HttpObject)` method, I called `context.writeAndFlush(httpObject)` to send out the full object. So, what am I missing here?

**update**
As there is an HttpObjectAggregator in the client pipeline, the ClientHandler always receives FullHttpResponse, which is confirmed from these logs (copied from above):

```
2014-12-04 22:58:22.935 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-1] INFO  ClientHandler:messageReceived(): Received HTTP response:
DefaultFullHttpResponse(decodeResult: success)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you only forward the "header" part of the received message, not the body part (next buffers).

But as you use HttpObjectAggregator, it shall be a FullHttpResponse you get from the client, and therefore sent to the server.

In Netty, HTTP messages are split in 3 parts:

- header part
- body parts (chunks)
- end of chunk (empty one)

Normally, using the HttpObjectAggregator will merged all of them into one simple full message.

Can you double check if what you send back is really a FullHttpResponse with a body content (at each step)?

Also do you managed the retain() method on your FullHttpResponse in order that the client does not free the buffers before sending it back?

Comment: _@Frederic: The problem got fixed once I added `response.retain()` in `ClientHandler.messageReceived()`. Looks like somewhere in the process the reference count to the http count becomes zero before it is sent back to the browser, but I don't know exactly how. Anyway, thank you so much, man.

Comment: This the default behavior in most of the handler of Netty. This is to prevent memory leak. See the API where it is written. See for instance http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/SimpleChannelInboundHandler.html

Comment: If you are interested in how reference counting in Netty works, please read: http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html

Comment: Thanks, trustin, Frederic.